# JSP MySQL check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '?'

Tags: mysql, jsp, tomcat, prepared-statement

I don't get it. What am I doing wrong?

I keep getting this error message:

**com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLSyntaxErrorException:**

**You have an error in your SQL syntax;**

**check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '?' at line 1**

```
...
String sUserName = oUserBean.getUsername();

String sql = "SELECT player_name FROM mydb.tbl_account WHERE player_name = ?";

    try
    {
        connection = ConnectionManager.getConnection();

        oPreparedStatment = connection.prepareStatement(sql);
        oPreparedStatment.setString(1, sUserName);

        oResultSet = oPreparedStatment.executeQuery(sql);

 ...
```

Comment: don't write this code in jsp! read through this thread http://www.coderanch.com/t/289435/JSP/java/write-java-code-jsp

Answer (score 8):

```
oPreparedStatment.executeQuery(sql);
```

should be

```
oPreparedStatment.executeQuery();
```

The SQL string has already been passed when preparing the statement.

Answer (score 0):

Use `PreparedStatement`..

```java
PreparedStatement pstmt = null;
try {
    String SQL = "select player_name from tbl_account WHERE player_name = ?";
    pstmt.setString(1, "Ur Value")
    pstmt = conn.prepareStatement();
    ...
}
catch (SQLException e) {
    ...
}
```